# When we use Entity Framework, how to use triggers?

Tags: entity-framework, c#-4.0, entity-framework-4, ef-code-first, entity-framework-4.1

When we use Entity Framework, how do we use triggers?

When I call `.SaveChanges()`, the following error occurs

> An error occurred while updating the entries. See the inner exception for details.

create trigger in sql server

Comment: And what would the **inner exception** be?!?!? This message alone isn't even remotely enough to help you!

Comment: One thing has nothing to do with the other. If SaveChanges works without the trigger. Put it back in and execute some sql (directly)that will fire the trigger. If that works, then get puzzled.

Answer (score 1):

In this case, in the pop up window of exception, there is an option called like "Copy Exception Details onto Clipboard".  Click on this, and then you can copy it to Notepad, or Word which i prefer because it is easier to read. 
Then use Ctrl + F for Inner Exceptions, and there should be a detailed error message there. That error message will give you more SQL related information about why if failed.